# Go upwards to ancestor than backwards 2 siblings using Xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have HTML like

```
<span class="state">
  <label class="state button start" ...>"Start"</label>
</span>
<span class="name tracker_markup">
  <span class="labels pre">...</span>
  <span class="story_name">title</span>
</span>
```

[image]

I will always know the "story_name" portion, in this case "title". I need to click the label portion "Start". How can I do this in Xpath? I'm okay with Beautiful Soup but Xpath is easier.

Comment: Do you have multiple header sections? or do you have multiple start buttons?

Comment: both. each pivotal tracker story has a `header` section and `start` button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below `XPath` expression:

```
//span[span[@class="story_name" and text()="title"]]/preceding-sibling::span/label
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be this:

```
//header[.//span[text()='title']]//span[@class='state']/label
```

or

```
//header[.//span[text()='title']]//label[contains(@class, 'start')]
```

or with partial title

```
//header[.//span[contains(text(), 'part_title')]]//label[contains(@class, 'start')]
```

Instead of navigation I would find the unique section with this `title` and find the element inside it like above. You can try a lot of types of combinations with any `attribute` or text using full value or with `contains` for partial values.

Comment: What does the dot in `.//span` mean?

Comment: To search in current node, meaning in header tag -> in this case finds a header that contains anyware in it a span with that text.